# I need some assistance with list methods in Python, storing input given automatically by system and execution when called

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So i need to store input from system and trigger code block when given command via input matches with condition. Given commands are randomly produced by system and its not same everytime when codes are executed. What i do below is; i store input in a list until input become blankspace and which shows commands are over and it specifically stated in statement that commands will end with blankspace after last command. Read commands, input and values from that command list until there is no command to perform. I know this is bad practice. Since I am newb in this language i need some advice to change my code. Thanks in advance. Btw i cant change conditions in if statements as given commands via input is not the same but like this and more:

> append_it 15
>
> insert_it 0 25
>
> remove_it 30

Code works just fine i need advice to make it good code practice to improve myself in Python.

```
i = 0
command_list = []
while True:
    command = input('')
    if command == '':
        break
    command_list.append(command)
    i += 1

b = 0
arr = []
while i != b:

    command1 = command_list[b]
    b += 1

    if command1[0:8] == "append_it":
        value = int(command1[9:])
        arr.append(value)

    elif command1[0:4] == "insert_it":
        index = int(command1[5:7])
        value = int(command1[7:])
        arr.insert(index, value)

    elif command1[0:3] == "remove_it":
        value = int(command1[4:])
        if value in liste:
            arr.remove(value)

    elif command1[0:] == "print_it":
        print(arr)

    elif command1[0:] == "reverse_it":
        arr.reverse()

    elif command1[0:] == "sort_it":
        arr.sort()

    elif command1[0:] == "pop_it":
        arr.pop()
```

Comment: Unclear: Is this working code that you want to improve or do you get errors? If the firs: off topic here. If the second: error infos missing. Please [edit] and make more clear what you need

Comment: Code works fine but i want to make it good code practice for my own improvement. I will edit. Thanks!

Comment: If you want advice for code that is working as intended, you should ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I didn't know that thank you @mkrieger1. Sorry for inconvenience, i am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: @KamerBeratTopal You said, the code works fine, but how can `command1[0:4] == "insert_it"` ever be `True`?

Comment: well, i did some changes in code to be more clear. It was in my main language, its originally "ekle" so it works fine. I just forgot to change indexes. @Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve by defining actions to do in a dictionary, adding the inputted values as splitted list and call the appropriate function for the appropriate input:

```
def appendit(a, *prms):
    v = int(prms[0])
    a.append(v)

def insertit(a, *prms):
    i = int(prms[0])
    v = int(prms[1])
    a.insert(i,v)

def removeit(a, *prms): 
    v = int(prms[0])
    a.remove(v) # no need to test

def reverseit(a):    a.reverse()    
def sortit(a):       a.sort()    
def popit(a):        a.pop()


# define what command to run for what input
cmds = {"append_it" : appendit, 
        "insert_it" : insertit, 
        "remove_it" : removeit, 
        "print_it"  : print,        # does not need any special function
        "reverse_it": reverseit, 
        "sort_it"   : sortit, 
        "pop_it"    : popit}

command_list = []
while True:
    command = input('') 
    if command == '':
        break
    c = command.split()   # split the command already

    # only allow commands you know into your list - they still might have the
    # wrong amount of params given - you should check that in the functions 
    if c[0] in cmds:
        command_list.append(c)

arr = []

for (command, *prms) in command_list:
    # call the correct function with/without params
    if prms:
        cmds[command](arr, *prms)
    else:
        cmds[command](arr)
```

Output:

```
# inputs from user:
append_it 42
append_it 32
append_it 52
append_it 62
append_it 82
append_it 12
append_it 22
append_it 33
append_it 12
print_it            # 1st printout
sort_it
print_it            # 2nd printout sorted
reverse_it
print_it            # 3rd printout reversed sorted
pop_it              
print_it            # one elem popped
insert_it 4 99
remove_it 42
print_it            # 99 inserted and 42 removed

# print_it - outputs
[42, 32, 52, 62, 82, 12, 22, 33, 12]
[12, 12, 22, 32, 33, 42, 52, 62, 82]
[82, 62, 52, 42, 33, 32, 22, 12, 12]
[82, 62, 52, 42, 33, 32, 22, 12]
[82, 62, 52, 99, 33, 32, 22, 12]
```